# ASP.NET_SessionId cookieSameSite issue

Tags: asp.net

I am having issues with a third party site we are using to process credit card payments posting those payments back to our site (ASP.NET MVC) and the ASP.NET_SessionId getting lost.  This is happening in Chrome exclusively.  I believe it's due to their recent SameSite which you can read about [here](https://digiday.com/media/what-is-chrome-samesite/).  I can see when inspecting the cookie in chrome that the Send for attribute on the cookie is set to 'Secure same-site connections only' but locally it says only 'Secure connections only'.

I have made the necessary changes to my website locally and have this working but once pushing those changes to our live webserver (Windows Server 2012) I am still having issues with Chrome.

Here is my relevant web.config settings:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" maxRequestLength="4096"/>
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="60" cookieSameSite="None"/>
<httpCookies requireSSL="true"/>
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms name="RAMAUTH" timeout="60" slidingExpiration="true" cookieSameSite="None" 
   requireSSL="true"/>
</authentication>
```

The webserver has .NET 4.7.2 installed.

I think that's everything I need to do in order to get this working and like I said it works locally but not on the live webserver.  Another thing I noticed is when using the configuration editor in IIs (8.5) on the webserver it errors telling me it does not recognize the 'cookiesSameSite' attribute.

Am I missing something?  Is there a logical reason as to why this would work ok locally but not on a live webserver running IIS?

Comment: This might help you: stackoverflow.com/a/73422580/2526059