# Loosing my session ID (and thus session variables) in ASP.net C# after installing KB4535102

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables, sessionid

I am calling a Credit card payment provider (Vantiv). When the payment provider calls back my Order complete URL the Session Id changes and thus all session variables are set to `null`. It is proven to happen after `KB4535102 (or KB4535104 on the Windows 2012 R2 server)`.
Looks like the Thread is aborted without a command for that. After system restore when patch is removed, it works normal. Anybody has a hint? I'm looking for this a long time.  Thanks

> targetFramework="4.8"

It happens in an iframe or with `Page.Response.Redirect` or with `html` like this:

```
 Response.Write("<form name=\"frmCheckout\" method=\"Post\" action=\"" + URLMercuryCheckout + "\" >");
 Response.Write("<input name=\"PaymentID\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"" + PaymentID + "\">");
```

The code in html  you can find above, it also happens with

Page.Response.Redirect("https://hc.mercurycert.net/CheckoutiFrame.aspx?pid=8fcc6f32-3480-4868-9fa6-ecd7331a0724);

I first set up a payment request. In this request you need to specify:
OrderCompleteURL (payment ok url)  and CancelReturnURL (in case cancel button is pressed on the payment site). This webservice call returns a PID paymentid. After that I call the Payment website CheckoutiFrame.aspx with the paymentid.

When the user is entering the credit card and click the Pay button, it will call the URL in OrderCompleteURL. When coming back, the Sessionid is changed in my web environment. (Also when CancelReturnURL  was called my session is gone)

This result in all my Session variables to be gone. The first line where Session["Variable"].ToString() is used this error happens:

"An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WebMobile.dll but was not handled in user code"

When restoring windows before patch KB4535102 this does not happen and the Session ID stays the same and all Session variables are available.

Similar question also found in : [ASP.NET_SessionId cookieSameSite issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60807342/asp-net-sessionid-cookiesamesite-issue)

Comment: Please, share the appropriate code and error details

Comment: The code in html  is above, it also happens with  Page.Response.Redirect(URLMercuryCheckout + "?pid=" + PaymentID");

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73422580/2526059

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it was related to the "same cookie" issue. But the fix you pointed to (in that article) I tried already but it did not work. The issue is fixed now. Vantiv/Worldpay created this issue and fixed it. Unfortunately, this is a problem with B2B to large companies, your own system becomes depending on them.  It took a long time (over a year) to have them recognize it and fix it.

Comment: This in itself is not an answer to your own original question but rather a comment on someone else's comment.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32538484)